# How to get the height and width of chrome devtools?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

[image: Chromedevtool]
Is there any way to know the height and width of Chromedevtool when it **docked to the bottom**?

when it's docked to left or right , I can use window.outerWidth - window.innerWidth to get the width of it,sothat I can use some script to move devtoolpanel to right or left only by keyboard(not use a mouse). but when it's docked to bottom, How to get the size of it?